# Appending empty list within a loop

Tags: python, list

I would like to append an empty list within a for loop. Currently this is what I have:

```
iteration = 0
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    for line in logfile_read:
    line = line.rstrip()

    if 'Time' in line:
        iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)

        for t in iteration_time:
            iteration = iteration +1
            print iteration, iteration_time
```

Here, `iteration_time` is a list varying from 0.1 to 0.5 in increments of 0.1. The output that I get with this is:

```
1 ['0.1']
2 ['0.2']
3 ['0.3']
4 ['0.4']
5 ['0.5']
```

However, I would like to assign an empty list to `iteration` such as `iteration = []` and then be able to extend by `1` increment for every value of `t` within the for loop rather than using `iteration = iteration +1.`

Comment: Actually the list you showed is going from 0.1 to 0.5 , not from 0.0. Which is it? (Remember that `enumerate()` will start at 0, unless you use its optional second argument to change that)

Comment: Please show us all the code including the outer loop that extracts the line number by regex, and we can refactor all of this more elegantly.

Comment: what is the desired output ? it's not clear what do you really want to do.

Comment: Are you sure you want that line-number regex in the outer-loop, how is that all supposed to work if the line doesn't match 'Time\s+=...' ? Should we remember the last lineno and increment it? or else what?

Comment: The `r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)'` will match because my log file will always have `Time` in it @smci

Comment: @Deepak - You are printing the whole list `iteration_time` on the last line. I am wondering how you getting the output you have provided here

Comment: @Deepak: the 'Time' regex doesn't match every line, which is what I was asking. So, again, how are we supposed to do line-numbers on *each* line? Should we remember the last lineno and increment it? or else what?

Comment: Thanks @smci. Yes `Time` is not available in each line. For example, the first time `Time` is matched, the line number should print `1` and when it next matches `Time`, `2` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you don't just use the `range()` builtin function?

```
>>> for t in range(5+1): print t, t/10.
0 0.0
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
4 0.4
5 0.5
```

I don't see that you need to form the list.
But if you do, use a ***list comprehension*** :

```
[(t, t/10.) for t in range(5+1)]
[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.3), (4, 0.4), (5, 0.5)]
```

Actually we should use `enumerate()` as @Amit says:

```
for t, tval in enumerate(t/10. for t in range(5+1)): print t,tval
... 
0 0.0
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
4 0.4
5 0.5
```

But in fact it looks like you want to start from 0.1, not 0.0. So you use the optional second arg to enumerate():

```
for t, tval in enumerate((t/10. for t in range(1,5+1)), 1): print t,tval
... 
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
4 0.4
5 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks @smci. I could have used `range()`. However, this piece of code is within another `for` loop that strips every line of a file and extracts using regex. Hence, every time the value of `range()` would be `1`.

Comment: Show us all your code with the outer loop, and we can refactor all of this more elegantly.

Comment: I have now added the entire loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` to avoid counter:

```
for i, t in enumerate(iteration_time):
    print i+1, t

1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
4 0.4
5 0.5
```

Comment: Do you want output exactly like `1 ['0.1']`, where the second arg is a list of string, not a float? What's wrong with just a float? If you really want it, then do `print "%d [%s]" % (i+1, t)` Or `print i+1, [str(t)]`

Comment: I tried the way you put it @Amit. But I am getting `1 [0.1]` `1 [0.2]`, etc.

Comment: @Deepak - You are probably missing something.

Comment: @Amit - No, I am doing exactly as you have